# Custom Flip Segue in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode6

Here's my Code for my Custom Segue

```
class FlipFromRightSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
override func perform() {
    let source:UIViewController = self.sourceViewController as UIViewController
    let destination:UIViewController = self.destinationViewController as UIViewController

    UIView.transitionWithView(source.view, duration: 1.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut | .TransitionFlipFromRight, animations: { () -> Void in
        source.view.addSubview(destination.view)
    }) { (finished) -> Void in
        destination.view.removeFromSuperview()
        source.presentViewController(destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
}
```

I thought this works but actually the view changes only when the segue is already performed. What should I do so that the view changes when the "Flip" is in the middle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please clarify the intent of this? Is this within the context of a custom container view controller?

Comment: @Rob the first View Controller has a background and a button and the second one only a background (I can't go back yet)

Comment: I was just trying to grok whether there was some special intent behind using a storyboard segue subclass vs a standard presentation (with a flip transition style) or using the iOS 7 custom transition patterns enabled by transitioning delegates and animation controllers. If doing it with custom segue, you'd have to do additional work to keep view controller hierarchy synchronized with view hierarchy. Nowadays it's best to use presentation transition, use navigation controller, or use custom container controller. I'll outline the first of these in my answer below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As of iOS 7, we generally don't animate transitions using a custom segue. We'd either use a standard modal presentation, specifying a `modalTransitionStyle` (i.e. a fixed list of a few animations we can pick for our modal transitions), or you'd implement custom animation transitions. Both of those are described below:

1. If you are simply presenting another view controller's view, the simple solution for changing the animation to a flip is by setting the `modalTransitionStyle` in the destination view controller. You can do this entirely in Interface Builder under the segue's properties.

   If you want to do it programmatically, in the destination controller you could do the following in Swift 3:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal   // use `.FlipHorizontal` in Swift 2
   }
   ```

   Then, when you call `show`/`showViewController` or `present`/`presentViewController`, and your presentation will be performed with horizontal flip. And, when you dismiss the view controller, the animation is reversed automatically for you.
2. If you need more control, in iOS 7 and later, you would use custom animation transitions, in which you'd specify a `modalPresentationStyle` of `.custom`. For example, in Swift 3:

   ```
   class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

       let customTransitionDelegate = TransitioningDelegate()

       required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
           super.init(coder: aDecoder)

           modalPresentationStyle = .custom   // use `.Custom` in Swift 2
           transitioningDelegate = customTransitionDelegate
       }

       ...
   }
   ```

   That specifies the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` that would instantiate the animation controller. For example, in Swift 3:

   ```
   class TransitioningDelegate: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
       func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
           return AnimationController(transitionType: .presenting)
       }

       func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
           return AnimationController(transitionType: .dismissing)
       }
   }
   ```

   And the animation controller would simply do `.transitionFlipFromRight` is a presentation, or `.transitionFlipFromLeft` if dismissing in Swift 3:

   ```
   class AnimationController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

       enum TransitionType {
           case presenting
           case dismissing
       }

       var animationTransitionOptions: UIViewAnimationOptions

       init(transitionType: TransitionType) {
           switch transitionType {
           case .presenting:
               animationTransitionOptions = .transitionFlipFromRight
           case .dismissing:
               animationTransitionOptions = .transitionFlipFromLeft
           }

           super.init()
       }

       func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
           //let inView   = transitionContext.containerView
           let toView   = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)?.view
           let fromView = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)?.view

           UIView.transition(from: fromView!, to: toView!, duration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), options: animationTransitionOptions.union(.curveEaseInOut)) { finished in
               transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
           }
       }

       func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
           return 1.0
       }
   }
   ```

   For more information on the custom transitions introduced in iOS 7, see WWDC 2013 video [Custom Transitions Using View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=218).
3. If should be acknowledged that the above `AnimationController` is actually a over-simplification, because we're using `transform(from:to:...)`. That results in an animation that isn't cancelable (in case you're using interactive transition). It's also removing the "from" view itself, and as of iOS 8, that's now really the job of the presentation controller.

   So, you really want to do the flip animation using `UIView.animate` API. I apologize because the following involves using some unintuitive `CATransform3D` in key frame animations, but it results in a flip animation that can then be subjected to cancelable interactive transitions.

   So, in Swift 3:

   ```
   class AnimationController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

       enum TransitionType {
           case presenting
           case dismissing
       }

       let transitionType: TransitionType

       init(transitionType: TransitionType) {
           self.transitionType = transitionType

           super.init()
       }

       func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
           let inView   = transitionContext.containerView
           let toView   = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)!
           let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)!

           var frame = inView.bounds

           func flipTransform(angle: CGFloat, offset: CGFloat = 0) -> CATransform3D {
               var transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(offset, 0, 0)
               transform.m34 = -1.0 / 1600
               transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle, 0, 1, 0)
               return transform
           }

           toView.frame = inView.bounds
           toView.alpha = 0

           let transformFromStart:  CATransform3D
           let transformFromEnd:    CATransform3D
           let transformFromMiddle: CATransform3D
           let transformToStart:    CATransform3D
           let transformToMiddle:   CATransform3D
           let transformToEnd:      CATransform3D

           switch transitionType {
           case .presenting:
               transformFromStart  = flipTransform(angle: 0,        offset: inView.bounds.size.width / 2)
               transformFromEnd    = flipTransform(angle: -.pi,     offset: inView.bounds.size.width / 2)
               transformFromMiddle = flipTransform(angle: -.pi / 2)
               transformToStart    = flipTransform(angle: .pi,      offset: -inView.bounds.size.width / 2)
               transformToMiddle   = flipTransform(angle: .pi / 2)
               transformToEnd      = flipTransform(angle: 0,        offset: -inView.bounds.size.width / 2)

               toView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
               fromView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)

           case .dismissing:
               transformFromStart  = flipTransform(angle: 0,        offset: -inView.bounds.size.width / 2)
               transformFromEnd    = flipTransform(angle: .pi,      offset: -inView.bounds.size.width / 2)
               transformFromMiddle = flipTransform(angle: .pi / 2)
               transformToStart    = flipTransform(angle: -.pi,     offset: inView.bounds.size.width / 2)
               transformToMiddle   = flipTransform(angle: -.pi / 2)
               transformToEnd      = flipTransform(angle: 0,        offset: inView.bounds.size.width / 2)

               toView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
               fromView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
           }

           toView.layer.transform = transformToStart
           fromView.layer.transform = transformFromStart
           inView.addSubview(toView)

           UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: self.transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
               UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.0) {
                   toView.alpha = 0
                   fromView.alpha = 1
               }
               UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
                   toView.layer.transform = transformToMiddle
                   fromView.layer.transform = transformFromMiddle
               }
               UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.0) {
                   toView.alpha = 1
                   fromView.alpha = 0
               }
               UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
                   toView.layer.transform = transformToEnd
                   fromView.layer.transform = transformFromEnd
               }
           }, completion: { finished in
               toView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
               fromView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
               toView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
               fromView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

               transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
           })
       }

       func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
           return 1.0
       }
   }
   ```
4. FYI, iOS 8 extends the custom transition model with presentation controllers. For more information, see WWDC 2014 video [A Look Inside Presentation Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=228).

   Anyway, if, at the end of the transition, the "from" view is no longer visible, you'd instruct your presentation controller to remove it from the view hierarchy, e.g.:

   ```
   class PresentationController: UIPresentationController {
       override var shouldRemovePresentersView: Bool { return true }
   }
   ```

   And, obviously, you have to inform your `TransitioningDelegate` of this presentation controller:

   ```
   class TransitioningDelegate: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

       ...

       func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
           return PresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presenting: presenting)
       }            
   }
   ```

This answer has been updated for Swift 3. Please refer to the [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26088001/2) if you want to see the Swift 2 implementation.

Comment: Thank you so much for that detailed answer - I'll try this out later and I'm sure I'll give you the "green tick" - but I have one question. Why do you usually use this instead of Custom Segues? It's much more complicated isn't it?

Comment: You said it's because of the View Controllers' hierarchy but it worked perfectly in older versions of Xcode or iOS didn't it?

Comment: I'd suggest checking out the first 5-10 minutes of the WWDC 2011 video [Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102) which goes into a discussion of the importance of keeping view controller hierarchy synchronized with view hierarchy. (The "Custom Transitions" video talks about it too, but I think this 2011 video outlines the underlying issue better, IMHO.) Bottom line, you can make the custom segue approach work pretty well, but because the view controller hierarchy is out of sync, you might not get certain events passed to it.

Comment: And one last question: The "let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("second") as UIViewController" is this the View Controller I want to go to or is it the ViewController I go from? And how can I give a View Controller an identifier?

Comment: Do I have to give a storyboard ID to it?

Comment: Yep, it's the destination view controller, and you give it a storyboard id in IB.

Comment: Well, the segue actually works now but the second vc is black - earlier it wasn't - do you have an idea what COULD be the problem? Otherwise I'll look over my code again

Comment: If you're using the custom transition approach (point 2 above), make sure you do _not_ use your segue. Annoyingly, it's easy to accidentally keep both the old segue and the new `IBAction` at the same time, but you want one or the other, but not both. Other than that, I don't know why the destination would be black (if you didn't get a hit on the storyboard id, I would have expected an error). Anyway, the above code snippet is from a test project, and it seems to work for me...