# Card Transition Animation Swift

Tags: swift, animation, transition

can you give some tips on how to animate the transition when I modally present a new view controller same as Apple animates the view controllers in Reminder App, when opening the App Store from iMessage app, and also like Facebook in their Messenger app?

Comment: The easiest way to modify the nature of the transition is to set the `modalTransitionStyle` to one of the four pre-designed transition styles. If none of those are adequate, you can do you own custom transition animations like http://stackoverflow.com/a/26088001/1271826. Clearly, the animation there is likely more complicated than what you need here, but it shows the moving parts (set `modalPresentationStyle` to `.custom`, define a transition delegate that defines the animation, define a presentation controller that dictates what to do with the presenting view controller's views, etc.).